# Xcode problem with directory permissions

Tags: xcode, permission

I'm trying XCode4. I created a new project, told XCode to put in my `~/develop/` directory, but then I immediately get asked:

> **“Test project” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your
>   changes. Do you want to unlock it?**
>
> “Test project” is currently locked
>   because you do not own the parent
>   folder and have no write permissions
>   for it.
>
> [Don't Unlock]     [Unlock]

...which isn't true: my `~/develop/` folder is owned by me (staff group) and has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions. I write to it every day. XCode is running as my account.

Is XCode right? What can I do to fix this? If I press “Don't Unlock” it seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried pressing "Unlock"? What does it do? Also: is the file/folder locked in the Finder? Can you unlock it there?

Comment: What does `ls -led ~/develop/` - show - the extra information is the ACL for the directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19194547/6521116

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to that folder from Finder, you can click Get Info and manage the permissions from the bottom of the window. You can navigate there by using the Go To Folder menu item in Finder or directly navigating their.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Finder and right click on your folder and go to *Get Info*. After this process you can change the permission.

If you like Terminal for this job, [this topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574543/myproject-is-locked-for-editing-and-you-may-not-be-able-to-save-your-changes) will help you.

Comment: How does this differ from the previous answer

Answer (score -1):

After [changing my home directory name](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1428?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) Xcode gave the same warning on a project I was working on. The work around I used was to create a duplicate of the project.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! This site tries to be the definitive Q&A reference to all things Apple. For this to work, it is important to stick to the exact question when answering. In this case, while your workaround is a good hint, you fail to address any aspect of the question related to the cause of the behaviour, which makes the value of your solution questionable. If you can’t provide any insight into that, your suggestion would be more adequate as a comment to the original question than as an answer. Thanks for pitching in, and enjoy the site!